# Executing a script from jQuery GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sending a GET request with jQuery

```
$.get("/index.html", /*Adding '?update' to the request*/ "update",
function (data) {/* Enter code here */}, "html");
```

where data is my server's response. I'm sending back a simple script like alert() so the 'data' variable equals `<script> alert("Hello world!") </script>`.

I need a way to automatically execute the script. I could just .append(data) to an element but I'm having multiple appends so that isn't really practical.

What is the easiest and the most practical way of executing the script?

Comment: Easiest, but *non practical* is to get rid of `<script>` tags in your response and do `eval( data );` Other way is to use `append`, which will execute it as well. Usually doing this is a bad practice, so you need to reconsider your strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `.append` it, like you said, or use `eval(data)`, but then you'd have to get rid of the `<script></script>`. You can supply `eval()` a piece of Javascript code and it will execute that.

Please be aware that using `eval` [should be avoided at all costs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score 2):

I did some crazy stuff in a case like this but you may think it is extreme. In my case I had to store some functions in localStorage and execute them by history state ( when user goes back/forth ). I have created a json object similar to

```
{obj:'myObject', fn: 'myfn', args: myArgs}
```

then stored this data base64 encoded. then when I need it back, I simply decoded content and

```
window.[data.fn].[data.obj].apply(null,data.args)`
```

did the trick without exposing too much data and not using eval. Eval comes from Evil so I would stay away. =)

**UPDATE**

So in my case all main core functions are json objects at window namespace similar to ( not actual content but an sample)

```
Member = {  
   initialize: function (){
          //some process
   }, 
   render:function(memberId, selector){
          //Some process
   },
   //...etc }
```

So when I store each item it, I used something similar to

```
var data = {obj: 'Member', fn: 'render', args: [1,'#member-block']}
```

then encoded version will be

```
localStorage.setItem('data', btoa(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

> dmFyIGRhdGEgPSB7b2JqOiAnTWVtYmVyJywgZm46ICdyZW5kZXInLCBhcmdzOiB7bWVtYmVySWQ6MSwgc2VsZWN0b3I6ICcjbWVtYmVyLWJsb2NrJ319

Then when I need to call back

```
var data = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

would return my original data object. Since the main functions in my case are in window namespace.

```
 if (typeof window[data.obj]!=='undefined') { // same as window.Member 
     if (typeof window[data.obj][data.fn]!=='undefined' && typeof window[data.obj][data.fn]!=='function' ) { // make sure fn is defined and is a function
          window[data.obj][data.fn].apply(null, data.args); 
          // we pass same arguments to function call with apply. 
          // `apply` will give us option to add arguments dynamically without knowing its size. 
          // it can be null any number of arguments that needed for that function. 
     }
 }
```

Comment: looks like a very neat one there, I'll give it a try.

Comment: But also keep in mind that if your arguments include any type of function (like callbacks and stuff ) then they will disappear on JSON.stringify in order to create a base64 content. to avoid that I used `JSON.stringify(obj, function(data){  }) ` and converted functions in arguments into string by toString() method, and did same on JSON.parse .

Comment: a simple approach based on your solution would be to send a json response and .apply to run the function, with the downside of exposing a little too much. I think that would be a perfect solution the OP needs. but do u mind explaining this bit window.[data.fn].[data.obj].apply(null,data.args)